# Developer Tools - preserve console record

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

For Network, Profiles and Timeline, there is a record button, which preserves the log. Is there anyway I can do the same for console log?

Sometimes, if there is an error in the script or during post submission, the page stop rendering or redirects and the console log clears. Is there any way to see the previous logs.

Comment: Not sure for chrome, but there's always firebug for firefox

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Currently not possible. Star [this bug report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=77058), hopefully it will be implemented one day.

Comment: Just wanted to add that it *is* possible in iframes. On JSFiddle, the log stays persistent when you click the Run button again (i.e. iframe is reloaded but page is not). So you *could* create a workaround with this little code snippet: http://pastebin.com/rSxRsnnc.

Answer (score 42):

Click the settings button in the lower right corner. Under General > Console check "Preserve log upon navigation". I should mention that I'm using Chrome version 23.0.1271.101, so if you don't see the option try upgrading.

[image: Preserve log upon navigation]

#### Update:

As of Chrome 59.0.3071.115 you need to click on the Console tab then click on the little gear icon and check Preserve log.

[image]

Comment: thanks. I saw it in latest version.

Comment: thanks, It is very useful