# Save console output in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

How do you save JavaScript console output in Chrome across page loads? The output is cleared when you navigate away from a page, so if you have messages logged just before the new page is loaded, it's difficult to see them before they are cleared.

Comment: possible duplicate of [google chrome developer tool - preserve console record](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928492/google-chrome-developer-tool-preserve-console-record)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Right click on the log/console area and check the "Preserve log" option.

Comment: That isn't working on version 12.0.742.112 on OS X, but apparently it has been fixed here: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=77058