# Chrome console to file

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome, logging

I would like to store the console output from my javascript in a file.

Well, I would prefer to see the output in a file too see with /usr/bin/tail or other linux comand.

Does anybody know if its possible?, and How to do that?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646016/save-console-output-in-chrome ?

Comment: @LEOPiC: That does not have anything to do with saving the log to a file. @Juamin: Since you state "my javascript", perhaps it's feasible to overwrite `console.log` to intercept logs?

Comment: I'm developing with the HP enyo javascript framework and I need to press Ctrl-Shift-I for EVERY page I want to see the console output. It's a big pain and a slow developemt process. I'm looking for a solution, like to have all the time a logger to a file from the browser, but ONLY for the conole output.